# generating json from bad mysql-formatted dates in asp

Tags: sql, json, t-sql, vbscript, asp-classic

I was thrown in a new project, which is apparently more than just oudated. The application saves **opening hours** in a very weird pattern in the DB and this is driving me crazy for over a week now.

Please have a look at this image:

[image]

As you might see, the **opening hours** are saved in a pattern like:

```
dayFrom  | dayTo  | timeFrom | timeTo 
=======================================
monday   | friday | 07:00    | 17:00
saturday |        | 08:00    | 12:00
```

Just to prevent any misunderstanding:

> Open MO - FR from 07:00 to 17:00
>
> Open SA from 08:00 to 12:00
>
> Closed on Sunday

Now, this seems to be kinda off already, but sticking with that, a table could look like this:

```
dayFrom   | dayTo   | timeFrom | timeTo 
=======================================
monday    | tuesday | 07:00    | 14:00
wednesday |         | 08:00    | 12:00
thursday  | friday  | 07:30    | 13:00
saturday  |         | 08:00    | 12:00
```

So, now my problem: I need to make a loop (or something like this) to create a valid json-string, containing all these opening hours.

Right now, I have this:

```vb
jsonAppendix = "{""openingHours"":["
for i = 1 To cint(hoechsterTag)
    jsonAppendix = jsonAppendix & "{""dayOfWeek"":" & i & ", ""from1"":""" & rs("ZeitVon") & """, ""to1"":""" & rs("ZeitBis") & """},"
next
'Remove last comma
jsonAppendix = LEFT(jsonAppendix, (LEN(jsonAppendix)-1))
jsonAppendix = jsonAppendix & "]}"
```

If I have only a "monday-friday", it works already, but the 2nd (or next entries) aren't taken into account.

The output looks like this, which is apparently kinda correct:

```
{
    "openingHours":[
        {
            "dayOfWeek":1,
            "from1":"07:00",
            "to1":"17:00"
        },
        {
            "dayOfWeek":2,
            "from1":"07:00",
            "to1":"17:00"
        },
        {
            "dayOfWeek":3,
            "from1":"07:00",
            "to1":"17:00"
        },
        {
            "dayOfWeek":4,
            "from1":"07:00",
            "to1":"17:00"
        },
        {
            "dayOfWeek":5,
            "from1":"07:00",
            "to1":"17:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

But the "Saturday" is not being recognized.

My function looks like this:

```vb
SQL = "SELECT * FROM StandortOpen WHERE S_ID = " & iStandortId & " AND OpenArt = '" & sArt & "' ORDER BY Sort,OpenArt DESC"
call openRS(SQL)    

'day-mapping
tageV(0) = replace(rs("TagVon"),"Mo", 1)
tageV(1) = replace(rs("TagVon"),"Di", 2)
tageV(2) = replace(rs("TagVon"),"Mi", 3)
tageV(3) = replace(rs("TagVon"),"Do", 4)
tageV(4) = replace(rs("TagVon"),"Fr", 5)
tageV(5) = replace(rs("TagVon"),"Sa", 6)
tageV(6) = 7

tageB(0) = replace(rs("TagBis"),"Mo", 1)
tageB(1) = replace(rs("TagBis"),"Di", 2)
tageB(2) = replace(rs("TagBis"),"Mi", 3)
tageB(3) = replace(rs("TagBis"),"Do", 4)
tageB(4) = replace(rs("TagBis"),"Fr", 5)
tageB(5) = replace(rs("TagBis"),"Sa", 6)


'for example: mo - fr   
for each item in tageV
    'save smallest weekday
    if(isNumeric(item) AND item > "") then
        if(cint(item) <= cint(niedrigsterTag)) then
            niedrigsterTag = cint(item)
        end if
    end if
next    

for each item in tageB
    'save highest weekday
    if(isNumeric(item) AND item > "") then
        if(cint(item) >= cint(hoechsterTag)) then
            hoechsterTag = cint(item)
        end if
    end if
next
```

And the openRS()-Function:

```vb
sub openRS(str_sql)
'Response.write "SQL: " & str_sql & "<br>"
set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rs.open str_sql,conn,1,3
end sub
```

So basically: Mapping numbers to the days, iterating through (or compare them to get a timespan).

I'm using a `RecordSet` as well. Maybe I need to use arrays or something like this? Any help would be really appreciated.

> I can't alter the table nor the design of that, I have to stick with that gargabe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create the dataset in SQL Server, consider the following

**Example**

```sql
Declare @YourTable table (dayFrom varchar(25),dayTo varchar(25),timeFrom varchar(25),timeTo varchar(25))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('monday'   ,'tuesday','07:00','14:00'),
('wednesday',''       ,'08:00','12:00'),
('thursday' ,'friday' ,'07:30','13:00'),
('saturday' ,''       ,'08:00','12:00')

;with cteD as (Select * From (Values(1,'Monday'),(2,'Tuesday'),(3,'Wednesday'),(4,'Thursday'),(5,'Friday'),(6,'Saturday'),(7,'Sunday')) DDD(DD,DDD) ),
      cteR as (
                Select A.*
                      ,R1 = B.DD
                      ,R2 = IsNull(C.DD,B.DD)
                 From  @YourTable A
                 Left Join cteD B on dayFrom = B.DDD
                 Left Join cteD C on dayTo   = C.DDD
                 Where 1=1  -- Your WHERE STATEMENT HERE
              )
 Select daySeq    = A.DD
       ,dayOfWeek = A.DDD
       ,from1     = IsNull(B.TimeFrom,'Closed')
       ,from2     = IsNull(B.TimeTo,'Closed')
 From   cteD A
 Left Join   cteR B on A.DD between B.R1 and B.R2
 Order By 1
```

**Returns**

[image]

**Note:** The Closed is Optional.  Remove the "LEFT" Join in the final query

Now, if you want to create the JSON String in SQL Server, and you're NOT on 2016, we can tweak the final query and add a UDF.

```sql
Select JSON=[dbo].[udf-Str-JSON](0,0,(
     Select daySeq    = A.DD
           ,dayOfWeek = A.DDD
           ,from1     = IsNull(B.TimeFrom,'Closed')
           ,from2     = IsNull(B.TimeTo,'Closed')
     From   cteD A
     Left Join   cteR B on A.DD between B.R1 and B.R2
     Order By 1
     For XML RAW
))
```

**Returned JSON String**

```
[{
    "daySeq": "1",
    "dayOfWeek": "Monday",
    "from1": "07:00",
    "from2": "14:00"
}, {
    "daySeq": "2",
    "dayOfWeek": "Tuesday",
    "from1": "07:00",
    "from2": "14:00"
}, {
    "daySeq": "3",
    "dayOfWeek": "Wednesday",
    "from1": "08:00",
    "from2": "12:00"
}, {
    "daySeq": "4",
    "dayOfWeek": "Thursday",
    "from1": "07:30",
    "from2": "13:00"
}, {
    "daySeq": "5",
    "dayOfWeek": "Friday",
    "from1": "07:30",
    "from2": "13:00"
}, {
    "daySeq": "6",
    "dayOfWeek": "Saturday",
    "from1": "08:00",
    "from2": "12:00"
}, {
    "daySeq": "7",
    "dayOfWeek": "Sunday",
    "from1": "Closed",
    "from2": "Closed"
}]
```

---

**The UDF if Interested**

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-JSON] (@IncludeHead int,@ToLowerCase int,@XML xml)
Returns varchar(max)
AS
Begin
    Declare @Head varchar(max) = '',@JSON varchar(max) = ''
    ; with cteEAV as (Select RowNr     =Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL))
                            ,Entity    = xRow.value('@*[1]','varchar(100)')
                            ,Attribute = xAtt.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
                            ,Value     = xAtt.value('.','varchar(max)') 
                       From  @XML.nodes('/row') As R(xRow) 
                       Cross Apply R.xRow.nodes('./@*') As A(xAtt) )
          ,cteSum as (Select Records=count(Distinct Entity)
                            ,Head = IIF(@IncludeHead=0,IIF(count(Distinct Entity)<=1,'[getResults]','[[getResults]]'),Concat('{"status":{"successful":"true","timestamp":"',Format(GetUTCDate(),'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss '),'GMT','","rows":"',count(Distinct Entity),'"},"retults":[[getResults]]}') ) 
                       From  cteEAV)
          ,cteBld as (Select *
                            ,NewRow=IIF(Lag(Entity,1)  over (Partition By Entity Order By (Select NULL))=Entity,'',',{')
                            ,EndRow=IIF(Lead(Entity,1) over (Partition By Entity Order By (Select NULL))=Entity,',','}')
                            ,JSON=Concat('"',IIF(@ToLowerCase=1,Lower(Attribute),Attribute),'":','"',Value,'"') 
                       From  cteEAV )
    Select @JSON = @JSON+NewRow+JSON+EndRow,@Head = Head From cteBld, cteSum
    Return Replace(@Head,'[getResults]',Stuff(@JSON,1,1,''))
End
-- Parameter 1: @IncludeHead 1/0
-- Parameter 2: @ToLowerCase 1/0 (converts field name to lowercase
-- Parameter 3: (Select * From ... for XML RAW)
-- Syntax : Select [dbo].[udf-Str-JSON](0,1,(Select Top 2 RN=Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)),* from [Chinrus-Shared].[dbo].[ZipCodes] Where StateCode in ('RI') for XML RAW))
/*
Declare @User table (ID int,Active bit,First_Name varchar(50),Last_Name varchar(50),EMail varchar(50))
Insert into @User values
(1,1,'John','Smith','john.smith@email.com'),(2,0,'Jane','Doe'  ,'jane.doe@email.com')

Declare @XML xml = (Select * from @User for XML RAW)
Select A.ID
      ,B.JSON
 From  @User A
 Cross Apply (Select JSON=[dbo].[udf-Str-JSON](0,0,(Select A.* For XML Raw)) ) B
*/
```

Comment: Thanks so much John. I'll try this on monday and will give you feedback. Thanks for the effort. This looks promising!

Comment: Just a quick headsup - I'm going to give you feedback during this day. I don't know why you was downvoted, but my question was it as well.

Comment: @DasSaffe Not my first dv and won't be my last.  I'd just rather they had the courage to comment. --- Looking forward to your feedback

Comment: It seems like this is somehow exactly what I'm looking for (judging by your screenshots) - but I have problems transfering it to my case. Do you mind joining in a chat? (if I can figure out how to create one)?

Comment: @DasSaffe I've never initiated a chat.  give me a moment to find it

Comment: I generated one here:
http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139779/dassaffe-john-cappelletti